# Windows10で特定のIPアドレスからの通信のみ許可する事は出来ますか？

Tags: windows

現在、ある目的に利用しているWindows10 PCのセキュリティを考えて特定の指定されたIPアドレスからのみアクセス可能にしたいと考えています。方法としては基本的にファイアウォールで全ての通信をブロックした上で、特定のPCだけの通信を許可できないかと考えているのですがその様な設定は可能なのでしょうか？

ネットワークの設定に関しては素人の為、基本的だとは思いますがご存知の方居ましたらご教示頂けないでしょうか？

Comment: 念のための確認ですがアクセス元となる「特定のPC」側のIPアドレスは固定されているのでしょうか？ 動的に変化する場合、「ある目的に利用しているWindows10 PC」側に設定を施すことができません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。アクセス元は、言及されている固定IPアドレスで運用しています。